# how to get datagridView display content of list rather than just length

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

List  A = new List();
A.Add("Apple");
A.Add("Banana");
A.Add("Pineapple");

dataGridView.DataSource = a;

Result: is the length of each item in  the list rather than Item itself.
5
6
9
How can I make datagridView to display string instead of length.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-string-list-to-a-datagrid

Answer (score -1):

Try using a List to actually take the string values rather than representing them by the char[].Count();

For example:

```
List<string> A =  new List<string>();
A.Add("Apple");
A.Add("Banana");
A.Add("Pineapple");

dataGridView.ItemSource = A;
```

Comment: Also, note the fact that for your DataGrid, you used `dataGridView.DataSource `.  You need to use the `dataGridView.ItemSource`