# Adding data into list<string> from datagridview1.datasource

Tags: c#, list, data-binding, datagridview, datasource

HI,

I just came across good link and used that in my code..

[how to bind list to datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-string-list-to-a-datagrid)

I used

```
List<String> list_string= new List<String>();
DataGridView.DataSource = list_string.Select(x => new { Value = x }).ToList();
```

And now i have my values in the datagrid.

to bind my list to datagrid,but how to  reverse the process?

i.e.

i want to do something like this

```
List<string> myList = datagridview1.datasource as list<string>;
```

But i am getting `myList==null` doesn't contain any element.

regards,

Sangram Nandkhile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing `x => new { Value = x }` you are projecting a new [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) and is no longer a `List<string>`

In the same question your reference try and use the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-string-list-to-a-datagrid/479419#479419) and project out to a known type, that way you can retrieve the `List<StringValue>`

```
List<String> list_string= new List<String>();
DataGridView.DataSource = list_string.Select(x => new StringValue(x)).ToList();
```

With that you can:

```
List<StringValue> myList = datagridview1.datasource as List<StringValue>;
```

And than to finally get your `List<string>`

```
List<string> stringList = null;
if(myList != null)
{
  stringList = myList.Select(s=>s.Value).ToList();
}
```

Comment: some problem with the **DataGridView.DataSource = list_string.Select(x => StringValue(x)).ToList();** gives an error saying try.StringValue' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable

Comment: @Sangram, oops had a typo should be `list_string.Select(x => new StringValue(x)).ToList()`