# Bounded ComboBox AutoComplete Sort

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a bounded Combobox and it's data source is sorted but it seems that auto complete re-sort its items when I start typing.

For example I use this code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    With dt
        .Columns.Add("id", GetType(Long))
        .Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
        .Rows.Add({1, "John"})
        .Rows.Add({2, "Jan"})
    End With

    With Me.ComboBox1
        .DataSource = dt
        .ValueMember = "id"
        .DisplayMember = "Name"

        .DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
    End With
End Sub
```

Now when I type `j`, the Combobox suggest `Jan` but I want the first item `John`.

For unbounded Combobox, this works: [How to provide automatic text completion for a ComboBox control in Visual Basic .NET or in Visual Basic 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320107/how-to-provide-automatic-text-completion-for-a-combobox-control-in-vis) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386215/vb-net-combobox-auto-complete-behaviour-for-numeric-values) is For unbounded Combobox.

Comment: Is the `Sorted` property of your combobox set to True?

Comment: @dotNET, No. it is False. and I didn't edit any property of my combobox  other than in my above code.

Comment: I spent some time with it and it seems to be a genuine problem, with no easy workaround that I could think of. The list of suggestions appears to always be sorted alphabetically, even with custom source. However, one can this as a feature too, since an alphabetically sorted list of suggestions would be easier to search.

Comment: @dotNET, thanks a lot for your time,I really appreciate it. and yes you are right about that this is a good feature, but for my work I want to sort by `id` not by `Name`.

Comment: Depending upon how desperately you need it,  a somewhat more involved approach would be to create your own ComboBox using a TextBox and a ListBox. I have done this in the past and it is more work than it initially sounds.

Comment: @dotNET, yes I also do this before in VBA, but I thought there is a simplest way to do this with VB.NET.

Comment: I had a similar problem and in the end I concatanated the id and text to form the 'DisplayMember' in the dropdown eg.. 1 - John, 2 - Jan... if you don't mind the id being visible then that could be an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code in [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320107/how-to-provide-automatic-text-completion-for-a-combobox-control-in-vis) and now it works as needed:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    With dt
        .Columns.Add("id", GetType(Long))
        .Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
        .Rows.Add({1, "John"})
        .Rows.Add({2, "Jan"})
    End With

    With Me.ComboBox1
        .DataSource = dt
        .ValueMember = "id"
        .DisplayMember = "Name"
        .DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyUp

    ' Do nothing for some keys such as navigation keys.
    If ((e.KeyCode = Keys.Back) Or
        (e.KeyCode = Keys.Left) Or
        (e.KeyCode = Keys.Right) Or
        (e.KeyCode = Keys.Up) Or
        (e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete) Or
        (e.KeyCode = Keys.Down) Or
        (e.KeyCode = Keys.PageUp) Or
        (e.KeyCode = Keys.PageDown) Or
        (e.KeyCode = Keys.Home) Or
        (e.KeyCode = Keys.End)) Then

        Return
    End If

    Dim actual As String = Me.ComboBox1.Text
    Dim dt As DataTable = Me.ComboBox1.DataSource
    Dim dr = dt.Select("Name like '" & actual & "%'")
    If dr.Count > 0 Then
        Dim found As String
        With Me.ComboBox1
            .DroppedDown = True
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default 'to show the cursor again
            found = dr(0)("Name")
            .Text = found
            .SelectionStart = actual.Length
            .SelectionLength = found.Length
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

I added this line `Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default` to resolve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093067/why-combobox-hides-cursor-when-droppeddown-is-set).