# C# Search datagridview for duplicates

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Using **ms visual studio** and **csharp .net4**.

This is the code i have to check for duplicates

```
    public void CheckForDuplicate()
    {
        DataGridViewRowCollection coll = ParetoGrid.Rows;
        DataGridViewRowCollection colls = ParetoGrid.Rows;
        List<string> listParts = new List<string>();
        int count = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in coll)//379
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow items in colls)//143641
            {
                if (items.Cells[5].Value == item.Cells[5].Value)  
                {
                    if (items.Cells[2].Value != item.Cells[2].Value)
                    {
                        listParts.Add(items.Cells["Keycode"].Value.ToString());
                        count++;
                        dupi = true;

                        //txtDupe.Text = items.Cells["Keycode"].Value.ToString();
                        //this.Refresh();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        MyErrorGrid.DataSource = listParts;
    }
```

This is the **check** before it **allows the user to save**.

```
private void butSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckForDuplicate();
        if (dupi == true)
        {
            txtDupe.Clear();

            dupi = false;
        }
        else
        {
            SaveMyWorkI();
            dupi = false;
        }
    }
```

This is the data that it is looking at:
[image]

Now, I know the logic must be flawed since it saving regardless.
I'm basically searching through each cell on **pareto1** to see if the user has made any **duplicates**, if so it will not save and instead displays the part number etc in another datagridview....well that's the plan.

So could someone look through this and tell me

**1)** Where in my **logic** is this **failing**, also what about if the checks are correct?

**2)** Will the list work adding the info, if so is a simple **bind to a datagrid** view enough to display the results?

**3)** If this is just a really bad way of searching through could someone provide code that reflects what I am Trying to achieve.

Many thanks for your future comments.

UPDATE:: Ok thanks for the help, my algorithm now works, but my very last problem is displaying the part number that is duplicated on the pareto column, instead it displays the length.

```
public void CheckForDuplicate()
    {
        DataGridViewRowCollection coll = ParetoGrid.Rows;
        DataGridViewRowCollection colls = ParetoGrid.Rows;
        List<string> listParts = new List<string>();
        int count = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in coll)//379
        { 
            foreach (DataGridViewRow items in colls)//143641
            {
                count++;
                if ((items.Cells[5].Value != null))
                {
                    if ((items.Cells[5].Value != null) && (items.Cells[5].Value.Equals(item.Cells[5].Value)))
                    {
                        if ((items.Cells[2].Value != null) && !(items.Cells[2].Value.Equals(item.Cells[2].Value)))
                        {
                            listParts.Add(items.Cells["Keycode"].Value.ToString());

                            dupi = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        MyErrorGrid.DataSource = listParts;
        var message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, listParts);
        //MyErrorGrid.DataSource = message;
        MessageBox.Show(message);

    }
```

Even though the message box correctly displays the results? is it something im missing out when binding to my datagrid?

Comment: Couple of questions - why can't you do this during data entry, warning the user as they are about to enter a row that it is a duplicate? How much data do you have in the grid? Also, this question looks very similar to your last question, could you possibly make it clear what the new question is, referencing back to the old question. Finally, if you have more that one question to ask like you do here, it is almost always better to ask in seperate questions.

Comment: thanks for clearing it up. I would love to be able to check on data entry but not sure what the process would be and what event handler to use.  That's why I have an update button.  This question is similar but a new problem is the fact the logic is not working. Ive asked these questions to try and outline the problem and possible answers, but yes checking on data entry would be excellent.

Comment: It sounds like even when validating on data entry the check for duplication will still have the issue, in that your logic is not quite right (haven't had time to read over that properly). But once you sort that, have a look at the datagridview validation events - these fire both when a cell and when a row attempts to commit. In this I would check the underlying datasource (rather than the cells) for duplicates. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykdxa0bc.aspx

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-string-list-to-a-datagrid

Comment: With future questions please try and keep it to one clear question each, rather than grouping several together, and try to avoid modifying the original question so much that it changes the intent of the question. Both these things make it hard to answer questions well and limit the usefulness of the post for future people. That aside though, sounds like you are on the right track now :)

Comment: ah sorry I thought it was good manners to update the people on the post with any new information or if any information has changed, never sure when to open up a new question then get told its too similar, or save into 1 and change and get told its confusing! hehe I'll make sure to think a little more before making a new post.

Comment: No problem at all - far better to update on information as it changes. If you find that you have something of an answer then post that as your own answer. I'm going to post in a second some example code showing validation at dataentry that should perform a lot better than your current code. Also, if you do want to validate everything afterwards I would recommend working with the underlying data to avoid having the delve through the rows and cells, and also check your logic - all those loops look unnecessary, linq will certainly tidy it, or perhaps just refactoring carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example showing how to perform validation during dataentry. There are various ways you can customise how the errors appear (including some sort of custom dialog to resolve errors) that might give you a better solution.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingSource bs;
    DataTable dt;    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingList<BindingClass> data = new BindingList<BindingClass>
            { 
                new BindingClass{ Name = "one" }, 
                new BindingClass { Name = "two"} 
            };

        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        dataGridView1.CellValidating += new DataGridViewCellValidatingEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValidating);

    }

    void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Index != e.RowIndex & !row.IsNewRow)
            {
                if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == e.FormattedValue.ToString())
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText =
                        "Duplicate value not allowed";                    

                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = string.Empty;
    }

} 

    public class BindingClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Naturally this won't always fit your requirements of what users like to work with but I thought it could help to see another option.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing comparisons with **==** and **!=** .

`items.Cells[5].Value` exposes an object.

In your case this is most likely doing an equality check based on reference equality, which is probably not what your want. Try using something like `items.Cells[5].Value.Equals(item.Cells[5].Value)`

Please also consider solving such problems on the simplest abstractions available. E.g. if you had the grid bound to a collection of objects, then you could perform the cleanup operation against that collection of objects, disregarding any UI you bolt on top of it.

You can also consider using the **Distinct** extension method from the LINQ namespace and provide it an `IEqualityComparer`<sup>*</sup> to make sure the most efficient code for removing duplicates available in the .NET Framework is used by you.

---

<sup>*)</sup> [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) is an abstraction that allows you to define in one place when you consider two objects to be equal. *Distinct* provides an overload where you can specify such a comparer.

Comment: on object equality, how do you ask for a condition for non-equality or would you simple put your code in the else after the if?

Comment: how about `!obj.Equals(obj2)` ?

Comment: so the value is the object for the comparison? so :   items.Cells[5].!Value.Equals(item.Cells[5].Value)?? does that work, seems strange to me

Comment: Well, you are comparing cell values, aren't you? Just write the ! in front of the comparison: `!items.Cells[2].Value.Equals(item.Cells[2].Value)`

Comment: me overcomplicating things -.- i thought since the objects require.equals as a method i presumed there was an equivalent opposite......: do you think LINQ is the way to go btw? i only ask because ive never got it to work before hence my nested loops. woul love top scrap the nests for some cleaner logic

Comment: Well this i didnt expect, it errors at the 1st IF condition with a nullreference handle.  hmm do I really need to reference nulls in my condition?? didn't think I would need to unless my way of looking through data is the problem.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. @ items.Cells[5].Value.Equals(item.Cells[5].Value)

Comment: ok i did a check for nulls but there is no difference the error remains. heres my new condition : ((items.Cells[5].Value != DBNull.Value) && (items.Cells[5].Value.Equals(item.Cells[5].Value)))

Comment: just an update, there are 379 records, BUT there appears to be a blank row at the end of the datagridview, which is when it errors. so i need to add a if to the other nested IFs to check for null 1st i think. ill kepp you posted

Answer (score 0):

See if this can work for you

```
 var dup = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Distinct().Where(g => g.Index != 0);
```

Excluding row with index 0. It is header row.

Comment: My bet is, this won't work, as the default equality comparison for a DataGridViewRow is most likely reference equality.

Comment: his condition for duplicacy is different.

Comment: i would much prefer to use LINQ to achive my checking for duplicates, but Ive never had any luck with it.  Thats why im using nested loops, but if you have a LINQ version of what im trying to do im more than happy to test it