# Unable to bind data to DataGridView by using BindingList in WinForm application

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview

I am reading data from excel file (.csv) and storing that data to `List<String>`. I want to display this data to `DataGridView` but for some reason I am seeing total `length of String` in `Grid`.

Following is my code :

CODE:

```
private void btnImportFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    dialog.Filter = "CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv)|*.csv";
    dialog.FilterIndex = 1;
    dialog.Multiselect = false;

    var userClickedOK = dialog.ShowDialog();

    if (userClickedOK.ToString().Equals("OK"))
    {
        this.lblImportedFileName.Text = dialog.SafeFileName;

        System.IO.Stream fileStream = dialog.OpenFile();

        using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            var list = new List<String>();
            var line = String.Empty;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) //Reading value and adding it to the list.
            {
                list.Add(line);

            }

            BindingList<String> view = new BindingList<String>(list);
            this.gridExcelResults.DataSource = view; // Binding list to grid

            //Also tried
            this.gridExcelResults.DataSource = list; // This also gives me same result.

        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

EXCEL DATA:

[image]

EXPECTED RESULT:

I just want to display these three fields on `Grid`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I asked a very similar question once:http://stackoverflow.com/q/11769509/293078

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this question:
[How to bind a List<string> to a DataGridView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-liststring-to-a-datagridview-control)

In your case you are using a `BindingList<string>` but the logic is the same. The DataGridView is looking for object properties to bind, `String` however, only has the property length.

Comment: Instead of `this.gridExcelResults.DataSource = list` I tried `this.gridExcelResults.DataSource = list.Select(x => new { StructuredFields = x}).ToList();` and it is working. Thank you