# How can I bind my List<string> to a datagridView?

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, bindinglist

i am trying to display the contents of a List in a datagridview using the following code.

```
List<string> data = new List<string>(); 
dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```

I am adding my data into the List in a backgroundWorker. If I change **List** to **BindingList**, I get an error saying

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'dataGridView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

however if I use List, I get a 3rd column when the datagrid is shown it which only contains the legth of the string for each entry in Categories.

Does anyone know how to get the datagrid to show the string contents instead of the string length while using a BackgroundWorker?

---

```
    private void OnBackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {            
        importExcelFile();            
    }

    private void importExcelFile()
    {
        // hard coded file name for testing. 
        TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"E:\\test.csv");
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");

        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            //Processing row
            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
            foreach (string field in fields)
            {
                //TODO: Process field
                data.Add(field);
            }
        }
        parser.Close();
    }

    private void loadFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += OnBackgroundWorkerDoWork;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void OnBackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }
```

Comment: Show the rest of your code, in particular your do work method and how you pass the list to the BG worker

Comment: Are you waiting for the data to be finished adding into the List before you assign to DataSource?

Comment: You need to pass `data` out of the Bg worker thread and into this function: `private void loadFileToolStripMenuItem_Click`. The compiler gives you all the info you need. It also looks like you're setting some properties of the datagridview within the worker thread. The data grid view is defined in the _UI_ thread, you are trying to update it from the _background worker thread_. You can pass data between threads using delegates or by the `ProgressChanged` or `RunWorkerCompleted` events

Comment: I added the RunWorkerCompleted and I still get a 3rd column added with the Length of the string (not the content)

Comment: @CocoaDev Right, but you aren't passing data out of the bg worker thread are you? You can pass data between threads using delegates or the events listed above. You can access the data with something like: `MyType obj = (MyType)sender;` and you are still accessing the datagridview within the bg worker thread which will result in cross threading issues... referring to this line `dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "URL";`. You need to rethink your approach with thread safety in mind.

Comment: @DGibbs i removed those lines because you're right. I didn't update the code on the page until now. How can I change the name of the 3rd column to URL or how can I bind my list to the 1st column where it used to say URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass list with `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress`. I allows to pass progress and custom object ([full dentition on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx)). Handling this event is UI thread so it will be correct.

If you need this on the end, just use RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result ([again definition on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.aspx))

Comment: There is no Error message. I can't see the data being listed in my dataGridView. I see the length of the string (in this case the URL)

Answer (score 1):

Please create a delegate and invoke the delegate using `control.Invoke`

You can use Invoke like this:

```
private void AddToListBox(object oo)
{
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { listBox.Items.Add(oo); }));
}
```

More about [Background Worker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)

Good luck!

Comment: There is no Error message. I can't see the data being listed in my dataGridView. I see the length of the string (in this case the URL)

Comment: A control created in the UI thread cannot be accessed in another thread in normal fashion, so you have to do what i say :)

Comment: Yes that ONLY occurs if i use a BindingList. I am using a regular List. Should I be using a BindingList instead? If so then how would it be helpful?

Comment: keep in mind, if you work with Background Worker you should do that just search about Invoke and BackgroundWorker - and i have used it many times :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [How to bind a List<string> to a DataGridView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-string-list-to-a-datagrid)

I created a class

```
public class StringValue
{
    public StringValue(string s)
    {
        _value = s;
    }
    public string Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }
    string _value;
}
```

then changed List to List

I am getting data but it's appearing in Column 3. I am only suppose to have 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code .I also faced the similar kind of problem but sorted it out using LinQ..

```
IList<String> listObj = new List<String>();
dataGridView1.DataSource = listObj.Select(x => new { Value = x }).ToList();
```

here,

```
dataGridView1 :- ID of datagridview
```