# DataGrid SelectionChanged MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

I'm just starting out with WPF and MVVM framework. I have a Window with two DataGrids and I would like to load data in one based on the row selection of the other. 
Has anyone got any advice or examples ,I've tried numerous ways but none seem to work out.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look I can help you a little bit, you maybe need to monitor the selected item (either with binding or an event trigger). When it changes to use the new item to fetch the needed info from your data and then re-populate the source collection for the second data grid.

Here is a sample code it can help you:

## Xaml

```
<DataGrid SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedValue}"
          ItemSource="{Binding Path=Source1}"/>
<DataGrid ItemSource="{Binding Path=Source2}"/>
```

## Code Behind

public ObservableCollection Source1 { get; private set; }

```
public ObservableCollection<data> Source2 { get; private set; }

public Data SelectedValue
{
    get { return _selectedValue; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedValue == value) return;
        _selectedValue = value;
        PopulateSource2();
    }
}

private void PopulateSource2()
{
    Source2.Clear();
    //Get your other data from DB here

    Source2.Add(SelectedValue);//This is just to show that it works
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am posting a simple code. You can change it as per your needs

View

```
<Window x:Class="MultipleDataGrid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceOne}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceTwo}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

View Code Behind

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MultipleDataGrid
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

View Model

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MultipleDataGrid
{
    class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly object _lockOne = new object();
        private readonly object _lockTwo = new object();

        private ObservableCollection<StringValue> _sourceOne;
        public ObservableCollection<StringValue> SourceOne
        { get { return _sourceOne; } }

        private Dictionary<string, List<StringValue>> _sourceTwoList;

        private List<StringValue> _sourceTwo;
        public List<StringValue> SourceTwo
        {
            get { return _sourceTwo; }
            set { _sourceTwo = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SourceTwo"); }
        }

        private StringValue _selectedItem;

        public StringValue SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                PopulateDataGridTwo(value.Value);
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }

        private void PopulateDataGridTwo(string key)
        {
            if (_sourceTwoList.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                SourceTwo = _sourceTwoList[key];
            }
        }


        public ViewModel()
        {
            _sourceOne = new ObservableCollection<StringValue>
                {
                    new StringValue("Key1"),new StringValue("Key2"),new StringValue("Key3")
                };

            _sourceTwoList = new Dictionary<string, List<StringValue>>();

            BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_sourceOne, _lockOne);
            BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_sourceTwoList, _lockTwo);

            _sourceTwoList.Add("Key1", new List<StringValue> { new StringValue("KVOneOne"),new StringValue("KVOneTwo") });
            _sourceTwoList.Add("Key2", new List<StringValue> { new StringValue("KVTwoOne"),new StringValue("KVTwoTwo") });
            _sourceTwoList.Add("Key3", new List<StringValue> { new StringValue("KVThreeOne"),new StringValue("KVThreeTwo") });
            RaisePropertyChanged("SourceOne");

        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            var pc = PropertyChanged;
            if (pc != null)
                pc(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }

    public class StringValue
    {
        public StringValue(string s)
        {
            _value = s;
        }
        public string Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }
        string _value;
    }
}
```

I have used the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-string-list-to-a-datagrid) to display the string in the DataGrid.

I hope the solution helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a crude but working example that I decided to type up in between Battlefield rounds...

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:Vm />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="Selector" ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" />
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=Selector}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public class Vm
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ObserverableGrouping> Source { get; set; }
        public Vm()
        {
            Source = new ObservableCollection<ObserverableGrouping>() { 
                new ObserverableGrouping("Group1"){ new ObjectModel() { Name = "A", Description = "Group1 Object1" }, new ObjectModel() { Name = "B", Description = "Group1 Object2" } },
                new ObserverableGrouping("Group2"){ new ObjectModel() { Name = "C", Description = "Group2 Object1" }, new ObjectModel() { Name = "D", Description = "Group2 Object2" } }
            };
        }
    }
    public class ObserverableGrouping : ObservableCollection<ObjectModel>
    {
        public string GroupDescription { get; set; }
        public ObserverableGrouping(string Name)
        {
            this.GroupDescription = Name;
        }
    }
    public class ObjectModel
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string Description {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.