# WPF MVVM: update datagrid based on selecteditem of another datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mvvm-light

[Class Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/521hh.png)

I am developing a wpf application using MVVM pattern.I want to update Second datagrid based on selection of first datagrid & if there is any change in Itemsource of second datagrid I want to update that change while the selection of first datarid is retained. Can anybody help me with this.

The need is more or less similar to this [DataGrid SelectionChanged MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091474/datagrid-selectionchanged-mvvm/24091638#24091638). But Whenever there is a update in the first datagrid collection automatically the data in second datagrid must be updated for the selected item of first datagrid.

[O8Lwl.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU0W8.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please add an example that shows the problem? See also: [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have set the INotify property for the classes linked to both the grids.First grid is getting updated on update of class object but the second one is not getting updated

Comment: The attached image does not help. Please edit your question and add some code. Add as much code as necessary but as little as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments I've created an minimal example which shows the binding. I hope this is what you were looking for.

MainWindow.xaml and code behind

```cs
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="300*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDevice}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto" DataContext="{Binding SelectedDevice}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FaultList}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
        <Button Content="Trigger DataGrid 1 update" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,10,10" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

// Code behind in MainWindow.xaml.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private MainViewModel vm;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vm = new MainViewModel();
            DataContext = vm;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            vm.AddDevice();
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel and MainModel

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using WpfApp1.ViewModels;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase<MainModel>
    {
        private DeviceViewModel selectedDevice;
        public ObservableCollection<DeviceViewModel> DeviceList
        {
            get { return Model.DeviceList; }
        }
        public DeviceViewModel SelectedDevice
        {
            get { return selectedDevice; }
            set
            {
                selectedDevice = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDevice");
            }
        }
        public MainViewModel() : base(new MainModel())
        {

        }

        public void AddDevice()
        {
            int rnd = new Random().Next(1, 100);
            if (!Model.DeviceList.Any(x => x.Name == $"Device_{rnd}"))
                Model.DeviceList.Add(new DeviceViewModel($"Device_{rnd}"));

            RaisePropertyChanged("DeviceList");
        }
    }
}

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using WpfApp1.ViewModels;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class MainModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<DeviceViewModel> deviceList;

        public ObservableCollection<DeviceViewModel> DeviceList
        {
            get { return deviceList; }
            set { deviceList = value; }
        }

        public MainModel()
        {
            deviceList = new ObservableCollection<DeviceViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

DeviceViewModel.cs and Device.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using WpfApp1.Models;

namespace WpfApp1.ViewModels
{
    public class DeviceViewModel : ViewModelBase<Device>
    {
        private Fault selectedFault = null;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return Model.Name; }
            set
            {
                Model.Name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        public string SerialNumber
        {
            get { return Model.Id.ToString(); }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<FaultViewModel> FaultList
        {
            get { return Model.FaultList; }
        }
        public Fault SelectedFault
        {
            get { return selectedFault; }
            set
            {
                selectedFault = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedFault");
            }
        }

        public DeviceViewModel() : base(new Device())
        {
            FaultList.CollectionChanged += FaultList_CollectionChanged;
        }

        public DeviceViewModel(string name) : this()
        {
            Name = name;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                Model.FaultList.Add(new FaultViewModel() { Name = $"Fault_{i} of {name}" });

            RaisePropertyChanged("FaultList");
        }

        private void FaultList_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged("FaultList");
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApp1.Models
{
    public class Device
    {
        private string name = "";
        private Guid id;
        private ObservableCollection<FaultViewModel> faultList;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public Guid Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<FaultViewModel> FaultList
        {
            get { return faultList; }
            set { faultList = value; }
        }

        public Device()
        {
            this.id = new Guid();
            this.faultList = new ObservableCollection<FaultViewModel>();
        }

        public Device(string name) : this()
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

FaultViewModel.cs and Fault.cs

```
using WpfApp1.Models;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class FaultViewModel : ViewModelBase<Fault>
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return Model.FaultName; }
            set
            {
                Model.FaultName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        public string Id
        {
            get { return Model.FaultId.ToString(); }
        }

        public FaultViewModel() : base(new Fault())
        {

        }
    }
}

using System;

namespace WpfApp1.Models
{
    public class Fault
    {
        private Guid faultId;
        private string faultName;

        public Guid FaultId
        {
            get { return faultId; }
            set { faultId = value; }
        }

        public string FaultName
        {
            get { return faultName; }
            set { faultName = value; }
        }


        public Fault()
        {
            this.faultId = new Guid();
        }
    }
}
```

Last but not least: ViewModelBase.cs

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class ViewModelBase<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        T model;
        public T Model { get { return model; } }

        public ViewModelBase(T model)
        {
            this.model = model;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

If you run the app you can click the button which simulates the update of device list in code behind. You then can select a device and the second DataGrid will show the FaultList of this device.

---

**Old answer**

**Update:** Related to your comments and the class diagram:

First thing:

I can only see one List in class Device. I assume this is the source for the first DataGrid? So you want to display properties of objects of type Fault in the 1st DataGrid. If so, where is the source for the second DataGrid? Or are you missing a Collection property in class Fault?

Second:

For data bindings you have to use [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) which implements INotifyCollectionChanged. You can not use a List<>.

Third:

Without seeing your code I can only guess what's going wrong. Let's assume class Device contains an `ObservableCollection<Fault> FaultList` and class Fault contains an `ObservableCollection<string> FaultDetails`. DataGrid 1 displays the list of faults and if you select one of them, DataGrid 2 displays some fault details. In your DeviceViewModel you would have the `ObservableCollection<Fault> FaultList` and a property `Fault SelectedFault`. Now FaultList has to be the ItemSource of the 1st DataGrid and SelectedFault has to be bound to the DataGrid.SelectedItem property. The ItemSource of Datagrid 2 has to be FaultDetails and the DataContext has to be SelectedFault. Maybe you need to propagate the change of the property.

I have not tested this! **A minimal executable example that shows the problem would be great.**

---

Old answer:

It's been a while since i wrote my last WPF application, but it could be that you either raise the NotifyPropertyChanged event for the 2nd DataGrid at the wrong place, or you raise it for the wrong Property.

DataGrid has a SelectionChanged event. Maybe you are able to access your VM from there and raise the correct PropertyChanged event for your 2nd DataGrid.

Comment: I have a class A which contains the list of another class B. The data to the second datagrid will be updated from this list of Class B in the selected object of class A. The first datagrid is responding well to INotify property when the class A object is updated. But the second datagrid is getting updated only when I unselect the selected item and select again. Don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
The List<Fault> in Device class, is updated while processing data for devices in business logic and the device data is updated in the first datagrid. The second datagrid is updated using a observable collection of Fault class in the viewmodel on selection of a device item in the first datagrid. 

Changing the List<Fault> in Device class to Observable collection will automatically updated new faults in the datagrid for the currently selected device?

Comment: Thank you very much for the minimal example.I have incorporated the similar approach.Will keep you posted in case I need any further help.