# DGV updates only when cell is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, datasource

I have a WFA, at the moment it has 2 forms.

The first form contains a DataGridView, with it's data source being a list.
When the user clicks a button, this opens up form2. Within form2 I have a bubblesort algorithm which sorts the list by one of it's properties. It then passes the updates list back to form1, and sets the new datasource to the bubbledsorted updated list from form2.

Now this works, the bubblesort works. HOWEVER, the DGV on form1 doesn't update UNLESS I click on individual rows/cells of the DGV. I have to click on each one individually for them to be in their new sorted positions.

Here's the code I have:

FORM1:

```
//This just shows Form2
private void sortByPriority_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fm2 = new Form2();
        fm2.Show();
    }
    //This is called by form2 to set the new datasource
    public  void refreshDataGrid(DataGridView p)
    {

        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = p.DataSource;
    }
```

FORM2:

```
private void sortPriority_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        bool tempforComp;
        string tempforDate = "";
        string tempforDesc = "";
        string tempforName = "";
        for (int write = 0; write < 10; write++)
        {
            for (int sort = 0; sort < toDoGen.task.Count - 1; sort++)
            {
                if (toDoGen.task[sort].Priority > toDoGen.task[sort + 1].Priority)
                {
                    temp = toDoGen.task[sort + 1].Priority;
                    tempforComp = toDoGen.task[sort + 1].Completed;
                    tempforDate = toDoGen.task[sort + 1].DateOfCompletion;
                    tempforDesc = toDoGen.task[sort + 1].Description;
                    tempforName = toDoGen.task[sort + 1].Name;

                    toDoGen.task[sort + 1].Priority = toDoGen.task[sort].Priority;
                    toDoGen.task[sort + 1].Completed = toDoGen.task[sort].Completed;
                    toDoGen.task[sort + 1].DateOfCompletion = toDoGen.task[sort].DateOfCompletion;
                    toDoGen.task[sort + 1].Description = toDoGen.task[sort].Description;
                    toDoGen.task[sort + 1].Name = toDoGen.task[sort].Name;

                    toDoGen.task[sort].Priority = temp;
                    toDoGen.task[sort].Completed = tempforComp;
                    toDoGen.task[sort].DateOfCompletion = tempforDate;
                    toDoGen.task[sort].Description = tempforDesc;
                    toDoGen.task[sort].Name = tempforName;

                }
            }
            DataGrid n = new DataGrid();
            n.DataSource = toDoGen.task;
            refresh();
        }
    }
    private void refresh()
    {
        fm1 = new Form1();
        fm1.refreshDataGrid(n);
    }
```

EDIT: updated and just to be clear - I need to use multiple forms (University Assignment), and nonetheless, it didn't update even when I had the sorting algorithm in Form1.

Comment: Why do you instantiate a new Form1 in the refreshDataGrid method?  don't you have already the instance available?

Comment: And why do you need a new form just to run a sort algorithm? You can place it in a function defined inside Form1.

Comment: Indeed it's messy. I'm just trying things to see if they work. I'll clean them up later. Paolo whoops yeah you're right, I've changed that now. Still doesn't answer why it's not updating when a new datasource is set.

Comment: @PaoloCosta University assignment. Need to use multiple forms.

Comment: Why is it downvoted.. At the moment no-ones tried to help, just criticised.

Comment: i didn't downvoat but it's actually very difficult to understand what you want to achieve. Maybe you should isolate the problem better, it seems the bubble sort is working fine, so why not exclude it from the question so we can concentrate on what you really need?

Comment: I answered with a simplified example concentrating on what seems more troubled in your code

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I'll make a simplified example that doesn't use the BubbleSort algorithm, I hope it helps:

This is the code of Form1 class. I define a StringValue class because of this: [How to bind a List<string> to a DataGridView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-liststring-to-a-datagridview-control)

```
public class StringValue
{
    public StringValue(string s)
    {
        _value = s;
    }
    public string Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }
    string _value;
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new List<StringValue> { 
           new StringValue("string1"), 
           new StringValue("string3"), 
           new StringValue("string2") 
        };
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(this, dataGridView1.DataSource as List<StringValue>);
        form2.Show();
    }

    public void RefreshGrid(List<StringValue> source)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
    }
}
```

The button click event opens Form2 and passes to it the grid view datasource. Here's Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 _form1;
    List<StringValue> _source;

    public Form2(Form1 form1, List<StringValue> source)
    {
        _form1=form1;
        _source=source;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _source = _source.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
        _form1.RefreshGrid(_source);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

After the click on the button in Form2 the DataGridView1's data source is refreshed with a sorted version, and Form2 is closed.