# DataGridView binding to an object's "ToString" property

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

I am binding a list  of objects to a Winform DataGridView. This works fine and has a column for each property on my object. I have now overridden the “ToString” on the object that outputs text based on the properties. I would now like to change my DataGridView so that it has a single column that binds to the “ToString” property of my object. Is this possible, as so far I’ve not found a way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind a List<string> to a DataGridView control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-liststring-to-a-datagridview-control)

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know binding works with properties, so you need to create property in your class, which will return result of `ToString()`:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Text { get { return ToString(); } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}, {1} years", Name, Age);
    }
}
```

and here a way to force grid to NOT create columns for anything except `Text` property:

```
grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() {DataPropertyName = "Text", HeaderText = "Custom ToString value"});
grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

binding:

```
var people = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person() {Name = "A", Age = 20},
        new Person() {Name = "B", Age = 30},
    };
grid.DataSource = people;
```