# How do I get a datagrid nested inside another datagrid to show a sub array of strings?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

The behaviour I'm looking for is when a row is clicked another datagrid shows a sub array of strings from the same source. Instead all I get is rows containing the length of each string.

[image]

XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="dg">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" />
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid Name ="dg2"  ItemsSource="{Binding Emails}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"  >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Email}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

ItemsSource

```
<Job GUID="5a790ed3-e3a3-4251-9906-36cfdcdc2fb2">
    <Code>something</Code>
    <Emails>
      <Email>gnhfgj</Email>
      <Email>gjfjgfj</Email>
    </Emails>
</Job>
<Job GUID="5a790ed3-e3a3-4251-9906-36cfdcdc2fb2">
    <Code>somethingelse</Code>
    <Emails>
      <Email>email</Email>
    </Emails>
</Job>
```

C#

```
string xmlFileName = "Jobs.xml";

XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Job>));
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(xmlFileName);
List<Job> load = (List<Job>)reader.Deserialize(file);

dg.ItemsSource = load;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer. This binds directly to the string.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding}" />
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4189977/1523703