# WPF - How to get ONLY one column of data from a group of data

Tags: c#, wpf, database, datagrid

For the data retrieval part from Database:

```
    public DataTable GetMagazineDetails()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionHelper.ConnectionString))

        using (var command = new SqlCommand("usp_GetMagazineDetails", conn))

        using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            temp_table = new DataTable("[COMPANY].[Magazines]");
            adapter.Fill(temp_table);

            return temp_table;
        }

    }
```

For the xaml.cs part where I want it to bind to a DataGrid, **particularly one column:**

```
        DataTable temp_table = usp_GetMagazineDetails.GetMagazineDetails();

        grd_MagazineListing.ItemsSource = temp_table.DefaultView;
```

My question is... How do I retrieve only one column of data out from the **temp_table** variable that I have created here. Is it possible? Or is there another way to approach it? Thank you very much guys :) Truly appreciate any help given.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you could do this.

```
List<string> columnValues = new List<string>(); // Modify and use respective data type.

foreach (DataRow row in temp_table.Rows) 
{
    columnValues.Add(row["columnname"].ToString()); // Use either 'columnname' or 'index'
}
```

Other option, use `Linq`

```
columnValues = temp_table.AsEnumerable()
                         .Select(row=>row["columnname"].ToString())
                         .ToList();
```

Now your binding should be

```
grd_MagazineListing.ItemsSource = columnValues;
```

Comment: Hi bro, thanks. I see the values shown inside columnValues are the values that I wanted. However, when it display on the UI itself, it shows me Length as title and the length of the values instead. How should I go about it?

Comment: How is your `XAML` looks like?

Comment: Just straight forward like this

Comment: <DataGrid Name="grd_MagazineListing">

                    </DataGrid>

Comment: Are you sure you are referring correct `columnname` in the query?

Comment: Yes I am very sure of it haha.. And I've just read from this post [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-liststring-to-a-datagridview-control). It seems related