# Want to display the list content in the gridview using windows form C#

Tags: c#

In the below code,

```
            List<string> unaffectedDb = new List<string>();
            List<string> affectedDb = new List<string>();
            List<string> nticdblist = new List<string>();
            nticdblist = Directory.GetFiles(textBox3.Text,"*.mdb").ToList();
            foreach( var nticdb in nticdblist)
            {
               using(var connection = new OleDbConnection("Data Source="+ nticdb + ";Persist Security Info=False;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"))
               {
                  string tablename = this.textbox1.Text;
                  string columnname = this.textbox2.Text;
                  string strcommand = " SELECT "+columnname + " From " + tablename + " ";
                  connection.Open();
                  OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(strcommand , connection);
                  OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                  OledbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                  if(reader.HasRows.Equals(0))
                  {
                     unaffectedDB.Add(nticdb);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     affectedDB.Add(nticdb);
                  }
                  dataGridView1.DataSource = affectedDB;
               }
             }   


        }
    }
}
```

I just want to display the two list namely affecteddb and unaffecteddb contents in the gridview , i tried for one of the list the grid view is not displaying in the output , kindly give some ideas

Comment: First of all, `adapter` is never user. You also missed `dataGridView1.DataBind()`.

Comment: if gridview didn't appear and no runtime erors you need only bind your gridview "dataGridView1.DataBind();"

Comment: @IgorGorjanc OP only wants to save the datasource where there are row changes and display it on the dataGridView, so it's not really related to the issue he's asking about.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid`!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView expects an object.

> Thats because DataGridView looks for properties of containing objects.
>   For string there is just one property - length. So, you need a wrapper
>   for a string like this

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/479419/6138713).

```
public class DataGridViewItemFoo
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public DataGridViewItemFoo(string value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

}

List<DataGridViewItemFoo> affectedDbFoo = affectedDb.Select(ii => new DataGridViewItemFoo(ii)).ToList();

dataGridView1.DataSource = affectedDbFoo;
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

UPDATE:

Here is a screenshot of a working example based on my answer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks , i tried the above contents are adding in the grid view but not displaying in output iam getting blank gridview

Comment: You can use dataGridView1.Refresh(); to refresh the grid view

Comment: Thanks, tried by refreshing also still the contents not displaying only blank grid view is shown , the list contains the path of the mdb files whether it will affect for displaying??