# BindingList<String> populating data view with string lengths not the string itself

Tags: c#, string, datagridview

Morning!

I have a `list<string>` which gets converted to a `BindingList<string>` as shown below. This then gets bound to a `datagridview` so that I can populate it with the appropriate values from this list.

However, instead of displaying the strings themselves it is instead being populated with the lengths of the strings. I have never worked with datagrids before so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance, I have attached the relevant section of code below:

```
            DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colExisting = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        {
            CellTemplate = cell,
            Name = "Template",
            HeaderText = "Existing Template",
        };
        findReplaceGrid.Columns.Add(colExisting);
        var bTemplatesInFiles = new System.ComponentModel.BindingList<string>(templatesInSelection);
        findReplaceGrid.DataSource = bTemplatesInFiles;
```

Edit:

`templatesInSelection` is defined as such:

`public static System.Collections.Generic.List<string> templatesInSelection;`

and instantiated as such:

`templatesInSelection = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();`

Comment: What type is your `templatesInSelection`? This behavior sound like named variable is a more complex Enumerable like `Dictionary` or `List<Tuple<T1,T2>>`

Comment: I've added the detail to the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, I know. But maybe somebody will come across this question like I did today trying to solve this problem.
What I did was to use a BindingSource instead of a BindingList and setting the BindingSources DataSource to `ListOfStrings.ConvertAll(x => new { Value = x })`.

I found this solution on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-liststring-to-a-datagridview-control).

Answer (score 1):

A `BindingList` is designed for Complex-Object-Binding.

If you try to bind there strings only, it will enumerate the chars building the string and only display the `Count`-Property.

A possible solution is this (ugly but working):

**WrapperClass**

```
public class StringValue {
      public StringValue(string s) {
        this._value = s;
      }
      public string Text {
        get {
          return this._value;
        }
        set {
          this._value = value;
        }
      }

      private string _value;
    }
```

**Usage**

```
var l = new List<StringValue>();
      l.Add(new StringValue("Hello"));
      l.Add(new StringValue("beautiful"));
      l.Add(new StringValue("World"));
      var bTemplatesInFiles = new BindingList<StringValue>(l);
      this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bTemplatesInFiles;
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

A simpler approach (as you wished)

First, add a column somehow (Designer or Code)

Then do:

```
var l = new List<string>();
      l.Add("Hello");
      l.Add("beautiful");
      l.Add("World");
      foreach (var s in l)
      {
        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s);
      }
```

Comment: Is there no simple way to simply shove a list of strings into a datagrid?

Comment: @JamesHughes Simpler approach added