# List<int> collecion cannot be used as datasource as DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have tried to assign the List object to the datasource of the DataGridView in windows forms application. But it shows the empty data in the grid. **Is there any reason for this or Am i missing anything?**

```
List<int> sample = new List<int>();
sample.Add(1);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = sample;
```

But if i assign **"List"** collection to the grid, it is working as below,

```
List<string> sample = new List<string>();
sample.Add("1");
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = sample;
```

[image]

Comment: The grid **columns** represent the **properties** of the objects contained in the rows. Since `int` (as well as other simple types) has no properties, the grid has no columns.

Comment: But string type List collection shows the Length as column. Is there any reason?

Comment: @NeelakandanK That's because String only has a property Length

Comment: Because `string` has a single **property** called `Length`

Comment: Of course `List<string>` is not really 'working' either.. You will need a (dummy) class with a nice property..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind a List<string> to a DataGridView control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-liststring-to-a-datagridview-control)

Comment: Simple select items of your list  to an anonymous type containing a property and bind the result to `DataGridView`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, Thanks for your information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's working the it does, is that DataGridView looks for properties to show on the object. String has one property, Length, so it's shown on the grid. Integer doesn't have any properties.

To make it work, you could create a new class that has a property of type int. You can then give a list of those custom objects to the DataGridView and control what is shown.

**Edit:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/479419/6625726) has an example on how to solve your problem.

Comment: @NeelakandanK No problem, feel free to mark this as an answer to your question if you feel like it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView requires objects in the list to have properties. String has property "Length", so it is shown. The number 1 is the length of the string, not the content of string.

If you don't want to create new class, you can use anonymous types like this:

```
List<int> sample = new List<int>();
sample.Add(1);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = sample.Select(k=> new {Value = k}).ToList();
```