# using lambda, how to apply an existing function to all elements of a list?

Tags: c#, lambda

Excuse me, a quick question:

I have a list of strings, string are full paths of some files. I would like to get only the filename without the path neither the extension for **each** string (and to understand lambda more)

Based on the lambda expression in [How to bind a List to a DataGridView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3225897/5890227) I am trying something like the below:

```
FilesName = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath).ToList(); // full path
List<string> FilesNameWithoutPath = AllVideosFileNames.ForEach(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x)); // I want only the filename
AllVideosGrid.DataSource = FilesNameWithoutPath.ConvertAll(x => new { Value = x }); // to then bind it with the grid
```

The error is:

> Can not convert void() to List of string

So I want to apply `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` for each string in `FilesName`. And would appreciate any extra description on how Lamba works in this case.

Comment: `AllVideosFileNames.Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x)).ToList(); `  you need to extract a list rather than just doing a `foreach` which yields nothings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ForEach` will execute some code on each item in your list, but will not return anything (see: [`List<T>.ForEach Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx)). What you want to do is `Select` the result of the method (see: [`Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult> Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)), which would look something like:

```
List<string> FilesNameWithoutPath = AllVideosFileNames
    .Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) method which takes each element in the list and applies the given function to them, but it doesn't return anything. So what you are doing basically is getting each file name and throwing them away.

What you need is a `Select` instead of `ForEach`:

```
var fileNamesWithoutPath = AllVideosFileNames
                              .Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x))
                              .ToList();
AllVideosGrid.DataSource =  fileNamesWithoutPath;
```

This will project each item, apply `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` to them and return the result, then you put that result into a list by `ToList`.

Note that you can also shorten the `Select` using a method group without declaring a lambda variable:

```
.Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)
```

Comment: Except that I need the `ConvertAll()` part for binding `List` to `Grid` (not `IList` as the linked question in OP states)

Comment: @KyleKhalaf you don't need `ConvertAll`, if you need a list of anonymous types with Value property you can do: `.Select(x => new { Value = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x) }).ToList())`

Comment: `ConvertAll()` to bind to grid is not my concern, and your answer to OP on how to use lambda is correct. Thanks