# WinForms C# Adding list to class Object

Tags: c#, list, winforms, class, object

```
  public class Wholesale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string WholesalerName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<string> PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Wholesale()
    {
        this.PhoneNumber = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

I have a class that requires a list of phone numbers.

```
   List<string> s = new List<string>();
        s.Add("22");
        
        wholesale = new List<Wholesale>() { 
        new Wholesale {CompanyName = "Test", WholesalerName = "Test", PhoneNumber = s, Email = "Test@gmail.com"};
```

Datasource binding with DatagridView.

```
var bindingList = new BindingList<Wholesale>(wholesale);
                    var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
                    dataGridViewAlbany.DataSource = source;
                    dataGridViewAlbany.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                    dataGridViewAlbany.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Company";
                    dataGridViewAlbany.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Customer";
                    dataGridViewAlbany.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Email";
                   dataGridViewAlbany.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Phone";
                    dataGridViewAlbany.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    dataGridViewAlbany.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    dataGridViewAlbany.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
                    dataGridViewAlbany.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
                    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridViewAlbany.Columns)
                    {
                        column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
                    }
```

Error:

```
  dataGridViewAlbany.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Phone";
```

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

How can I add a list of phone numbers?

Comment: You need to ensure your `dataGridViewAlbany` has at least 5 columns. Are you using manually-defined or automatically-generated columns?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the prompt reply.
I am generating them automatically by using a binding source/ list.

Comment: How do you envision a list of phone numbers displayed in a single column? Somehow stacked in a column, or a comma-delimited list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-liststring-to-a-datagridview-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add new property for phone number text e.g. like a comma separated string:

```
public class Wholesale

    public List<string> PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumberAsText => string.Join(",", PhoneNumber);
```