Binding DataGridView to List(Of String) displays length rather than the string
If I bind a DataGridView.DataSource to  List(Of String), the length of the strings are displayed, rather than the strings themselves.
How do I display the string values instead?

So that you understand what's happening, when binding a list of items to a DataGridView, the grid will create a column for each public property of the items. The items are usually data classes with properties of types like String, Integer, etc. If your items are Strings then the grid will do the same thing, creating columns for the public properties of the String class. As indicated in the answer, you need to create a data class where your Strings are exposed via a property so that that's what you see in the column.

Why are you using a DataGridView instead of a ListBox? Is it because you want to edit the data? If not, I'd suggest the ListBox as a better alternative. If so, you'll have to think about how you're going to get the data back afterwards, so an anonymous type like that suggested in the first answer may not be the best option.

Thanks @jmcilhinney! Yes I found the solution in the C# tag, but there was no VB.NET version of the answer, so I answered my own question.

I didn't notice that you were the one who posted the answer. I just assmued that it was someone else.

The UI is read-only. Perhaps a ListBox would be a better solution, but the other tabs have DataGridViews with multicolumnar data, so this tab ended up using a datagridview too

@jmcilhinney haha yes you are too efficient, I was asking + answering my own question for posterity. Good to get feedback and for others to review, perhaps there are better answers to the one I posted (even though it is my question)!

@jmcilhinney, I've plagiarized your explanation and added it to my answer, I only showed the "how" and it is good to include your "why" in the answer. Hope this is okay! Feel free to edit my answer to improve it!

(This is a VB.NET translation of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3225897/741136)
When binding a list of items to a DataGridView, the grid will create a column for each public property of the items. The items are usually data classes with properties of types like String, Integer, etc. If your items are Strings then the grid will do the same thing, creating columns for the public properties of the String class. The String class only has the property Length, which is what you are seeing.
To solve this, we can use LINQ to wrap the strings in an anonymous type with a .Value property:
Dim ignoredFilenames As New List(Of String)

ignoredFilenames.Add("thumbs.db")
ignoredFilenames.Add("desktop.ini")
DataGridView1.DataSource = ignoredFilenames.Select(Function(x) New With {.Value = x}).ToList()


Shout out to @jmcilhinney for his improvements to this answer. Thanks mate!
